# Facebook FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate loginButton function syntax error

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swift3

i'm using Xcode8 and swift 3. So I fully converted my project to the latest syntax and now i get the error:

> 'Error' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

in the function:

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
//do stuff
}
```

The function in FBSDK declared as follows:

```
- (void)  loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
            error:(NSError *)error;
```

so I tried to change Error type to NSError but i get the other error:

> 'SignInViewController' does not conform to protocol 'FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate'

I don't know what to do. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that i've imported `RealmSwift` that have their own `Error` struct. So the solution is to use `Swift.Error` instead of just `Error`. Hope this helps to anybody.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate method is changed like below in Swift 3.

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {


    }
```

"didCompleteWithResult result" is changed to "didCompleteWith result".

Comment: Thanks for answer, i updated my code with your recommendation but error is persists

Comment: Please paste your stuffs that you have inside of didCompleteWithResult delegate method.

Comment: The error perstists even if my code is have only one `print("swift3")`