# Conforming to protocol - adding protocol stubs again and again doesn't fix the error

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk, xcode10, turbolinks-ios

So I have class FBViewController which should show a button log me in and log out (just to test FB login). I integrated this in newly created project and all worked. Then I reworked it into my app and it's not working. Not sure if it has something to do with swift version or sth else...
Using Xcode 10.0

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class FBViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let btnFBLogin = FBSDKLoginButton()
        btnFBLogin.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
        btnFBLogin.delegate = self
        btnFBLogin.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(btnFBLogin)

        if FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil{
            print("Logged IN ALREADY")
            printInfo()
        }else{
            print("not logged in")
        }

    }

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        if error != nil{
            print(" error")
      //      print(error.localizedDescription)
        }else if result.isCancelled {
            print("User cancelled.")
        }
        else {
            print("Logge IN!")
            printInfo()
        }
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("logged out")
    }

    func printInfo(){


        if(FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil){

            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id,name , first_name, last_name , email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in

                guard let Info = result as? [String: Any] else { return }

                if let userName = Info["name"] as? String
                {
                    print(userName)
                }

            })
        }
    }

}
```

FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate

```
/**
 @protocol
  A delegate for `FBSDKLoginButton`
 */
@protocol FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate <NSObject>

@required
/**
  Sent to the delegate when the button was used to login.
 @param loginButton the sender
 @param result The results of the login
 @param error The error (if any) from the login
 */
- (void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
                error:(NSError *)error;

/**
  Sent to the delegate when the button was used to logout.
 @param loginButton The button that was clicked.
*/
- (void)loginButtonDidLogOut:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton;

@optional
/**
  Sent to the delegate when the button is about to login.
 @param loginButton the sender
 @return YES if the login should be allowed to proceed, NO otherwise
 */
- (BOOL) loginButtonWillLogin:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton;

@end
```

Adding protocol stubs adds just 1 function (loginButton...) which is already implemented and it seems like it doesn't recognize it.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7EZ0.png]

I tried cleaning project, removing derived data, restarting but still, it keeps giving me the same error:

> Type 'FBViewController' does not conform to protocol
>   'FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate'

Help appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Can you please add all the FB Pods dependent versions, as appeared on the Podfile.lock file?

Comment: - Bolts (1.9.0):
    - Bolts/AppLinks (= 1.9.0)
    - Bolts/Tasks (= 1.9.0)
  - Bolts/AppLinks (1.9.0):
    - Bolts/Tasks
  - Bolts/Tasks (1.9.0)
  - FBSDKCoreKit (4.38.1):
    - Bolts (~> 1.9)
  - FBSDKLoginKit (4.38.1):
    - FBSDKCoreKit

Comment: Did you click on the `Fix` button? What happened?

Comment: @Honey yes,I did, it just adds the same function always - loginButton(....), which doesn't fix the problem, its like it doesn't recognize, feels like bug in xcode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after a lot of searching I have found out an answer to this problem which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567267/facebook-fbsdkloginbuttondelegate-loginbutton-function-syntax-error)

I have imported Turbolinks-ios which had its own Error struct, I had to use Swift.Error in method stub -

```
 func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Swift.Error!) {...
```

Comment: So technically the Turbolinks-ios import caused your Error to be their type and not Swift.Error?
Nice catch!

Comment: @YanivH Yes, the post I put link above helped me to realize this. It’s a pity that Xcode doesn’t tell you more sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

For others who may have come here to have problems with a class Delegate from Cocoapod.

So the issue that was having I was adding the protocols

```
func photo(captured: UIImage?, currentStep: StepEnum) {
```

But they were always asking to repeat because the cocoapod project and my project had the same class name "StepEnum" to fix that I just had to change my class name and it was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall and reinstall the pods doing the following steps:

Remove all the dependencies from your .podfile (or just comment by adding a `#` at the beginning of the line )
Run `pod install` on your project directory and waiting for uninstall all pods removed
re-add the pods dependencies and run `pod install` again
Clean your project e build again

---

Plus: sometimes i got similar problems that are solved simply removing the functions that are required e already implemented, and try to re-adding using the auto-complete of the Xcode.

For exemple, start typing the method, choose the right on auto-complete list(if doesn't appear use `^+Space`), and press enter:
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2yEY.png)

Comment: Tried all suggestions multiple times, still receiving same error:  Protocol requires function 'loginButton(_:didCompleteWith:error:)' with type '(FBSDKLoginButton?, FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult?, Error?) -> Void'; do you want to add a stub?